# VisualSearch.js Sub Facets

Tags: javascript, cakephp, backbone.js

I am trying to implement a VisualSearch.js Query box that can be used to search the attributes of particular objects.  VisualSearch.js provides Facets that can have categories but does any one know of a way that I can load a facet for the model name .e.g 'user') then once clicked/selected load a second sub facet with a list of attributes before then giving the user a chance to finally click on the values which will be load via a JSON call.  I have searched and cannot find any reference to this sort of functionality but I may just be using the incorrect term "Sub Facet".

Here is a JSFiddle I have been playing with.  http://jsfiddle.net/Savvy84/HRuAP/13/

```
var visualSearch = VS.init({
    container: $('#visual_search'),
    query: '',
    callbacks: {
        search: function(query, searchCollection) {},
        facetMatches: function(callback) {
            callback([
                {
                value: 'user.email',
                label: 'users.email',
                category: 'Users'},
                 {
                value: 'job.name',
                label: 'job.name',
                category: 'Jobs'},
                 {
                value: 'job.startDate',
                label: 'job.startDate',
                category: 'Jobs'}
            ]);
        },
        valueMatches: function(facet, searchTerm, callback) {
            if (searchTerm.length > 0) {
                //pass the facet to the search and let the server deal with it.
                switch (facet) {
                case 'user.email':
                    callback([
                        {
                        label: 'john.smith@example.com'},
                           {
                        label: 'jane.doe@example.com'}
                        ]);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    } });
```

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading through the source code I can see that to create this functionality I will have to fork VisualSearch.js and edit some of its classes.

http://documentcloud.github.com/visualsearch/docs/search_facet.html

Answer (score 0):

May be I am extremely late now to answer the question, however it may help some one. 
I agree with @andrewsavil that you need to modify the visual search library itself.

You will need to add the following code to search_facet.js file inside the setupAutocomplete function:-

```
// Renders the results grouped by the categories they belong to.
this.box.data('uiAutocomplete')._renderMenu = function(ul, items) {
    var category = '';
    _.each(items, _.bind(function(item, i) {
      if (item.category && item.category != category) {
        ul.append('<li class="ui-autocomplete-category">'+item.category+'</li>');
        category = item.category;
      }

      if(this._renderItemData) {
        this._renderItemData(ul, item);
      } else {
        this._renderItem(ul, item);
      }

    }, this));
  };
```